# QGIS Time Manager with Graduated symbols

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I have a csv file with lat/long, site name, and a temperature field (I have this for something like 105 sites, but am just trying to get one site to work for now). Each row has a different date/time.

I am trying to get time manager to animate them in order with color or size changes based on mean temperature.

I get this error after I add the layer to time manager and hit ok (works fine if I don't have graduated symbols).

```
2017-03-27T10:26:42 0   Layer extents(datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 3, 0, 0))
2017-03-27T10:26:42 0   Trying to create time interpolated layer with interpolation mode: Linear interpolation (point geometries only)
2017-03-27T10:26:42 2   An error occured while trying to add layer test to TimeManager. Cause: 'Traceback:Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:/Users/justin/.qgis2/python/plugins\\timemanager\\timevectorinterpolatedlayer.py", line 53, in __init__\n    qgs.setLayerColor(self.memLayer, qgs.getLayerColor(self.layer))\n  File "C:/Users/justin/.qgis2/python/plugins\\timemanager\\qgis_utils.py", line 116, in getLayerColor\n    symbol = renderer.symbol()\nAttributeError: \'QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2\' object has no attribute \'symbol\'\n'Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/Users/justin/.qgis2/python/plugins\timemanager\timemanagercontrol.py", line 635, in createTimeLayerFromRow
            self.iface)
          File "C:/Users/justin/.qgis2/python/plugins\timemanager\timevectorinterpolatedlayer.py", line 76, in __init__
            raise InvalidTimeLayerError("Traceback:" + traceback.format_exc(e))
        InvalidTimeLayerError: 'Traceback:Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:/Users/justin/.qgis2/python/plugins\\timemanager\\timevectorinterpolatedlayer.py", line 53, in __init__\n    qgs.setLayerColor(self.memLayer, qgs.getLayerColor(self.layer))\n  File "C:/Users/justin/.qgis2/python/plugins\\timemanager\\qgis_utils.py", line 116, in getLayerColor\n    symbol = renderer.symbol()\nAttributeError: \'QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2\' object has no attribute \'symbol\'\n'

2017-03-27T10:26:49 0   Cleaning up interpolated layer test
```

My version: QGIS version 2.18.0 Time Manager version 2.3.2

Comment: Updating to QGIS 2.18.4 does not change the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

`qgis_util.py` module in Time Manager plugin folder has `getRenderer()` method that returns layer renderer object.

```
def getRenderer(layer):
    if hasattr(layer, "rendererV2"):
        return layer.rendererV2() # for QGIS 2
    else:
        return layer.renderer()   # for QGIS 3
```

Renderer object can be an instance of any renderer class shown in [this graph](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsFeatureRendererV2__inherit__graph.png)

`getLayerColor`, `getLayerSize`, `setLayerColor` and `setLayerSize` methods in the module use `renderer.symbol()` of layer renderer. But `symbol()` is just defined for `QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2` class. So if you use different style aside  'Single Symbol', you most likely get an error.

The same is true for QGIS 3.